# Is there a way to change data-url into href to middle click links?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm not able to middle click hyperlink due to the HTML code using href="#" and then using data-url="/redirect/...".

Is there a chrome extension or someway to deal with this so I'm able to open link in new tab. Here is code for reference

```
<a href="#" aria-label="1.01 
    " title="1.01 Purposes &amp; Origins of Government " data-link-id="1295115257" data-navigate="" data-url="/k12/redirect?url=https://learning.k12.com/d2l/le/calendar/2015232/event/38315900/detailsview" data-urlnav="" data-options="{}" id="c947" target="_self" class=" clickable  js-external-link" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: This seems _really_ specific for a very specific implemented website somewhere. Unless you do this a thousand times a day I don't think its worth building for this case. Otherwise just open your console and run `document.querySelectorAll("a[data-url]").forEach(a => a.href = a.dataset.url)` and it should open all those like regular links?

Comment: this works to an extent; is there a way to put this into something like this into tampermonkey and have it auto update every time I click and element

Comment: I guess? I don't use tampermonkey (or many extensions really), so I wouldn't be able to tell you about that. I have built an extension and you could run this as a content script easily, but that is a lot of hassle for this.

Comment: I'm going to be doing this 100+ times a day. If your extension executes the code every time an element update occurs and on page load, that would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Tampermonkey script that changes the links.

```js
function updateLinks() {
  document.querySelectorAll("a[data-url]").forEach(a => {
    const dataUrl = a.dataset.url;
    if (dataUrl && dataUrl.startsWith('/k12/redirect?url=')) {
      const newUrl = decodeURIComponent(dataUrl.substring('/k12/redirect?url='.length));
      a.href = newUrl;
    }
  });
}

// Run the updateLinks function every 1 secound
setInterval(updateLinks, 1000);
```

I couldn't figure out how to check for element updates so I just made it run every second. Thanks to somethinghere for writing the console command for me

Comment: Checking for element updates: `new IntersectionObserver( updateLinks ).observe( document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: [ 'data-url' ] })` - that should trigger when new elements get added, removed and when the `data-url` attribute gets changed on any element in the `body`. Here's the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver - But anyways, good stuff!